# How to refactor two similar methods?

Tags: java

I have two methods that wait for an email to arrive and retrieve emailID. They are static. Is it possible to do these methods better? Because many parts of these methods are the same.

```
     public static String waitForExcaEmailId(String fieldName, String subject)  throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String emailID = ""; int i = 0;
        do{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            emailID = getFakeMailID(getMessagesList(fieldName, url), MAIL_FROM, getCurrentDate(), subject);
            i++;
            logInfo("Mail ID: " + emailID);
            if(i > TIMEOUT_MAX_TIME_WAITING_FOR_MAIL_APPEARANCE) throw new RuntimeException("Email ID not found");
        }while(emailID == null)

        return emailID;
    }

    public static String waitForGoogleEmailID(String fieldName, String subject) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String emailID = ""; int i = 0;
        do{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            emailID = getGoogleMailID(MAIL_FROM, getCurrentDate(), subject);
            i++;
            logInfo("Mail ID: " + emailID);
            if(i > TIMEOUT_MAX_TIME_WAITING_FOR_MAIL_APPEARANCE) throw new RuntimeException("Email ID not found");
        }while(emailID == null);

        return emailID;
    }
```

Comment: If it's only the `emailID` creation that is different, you could pass a function into your method to supply the emailID on demand.

Comment: Can you show us what the callers of these two methods look like?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple `Supplier`:

```
public static String waitFor(Supplier<String> emailSupplier) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
     String emailID = ""; int i = 0;
     do{
         Thread.sleep(5000);

         emailID = emailSupplier.get();

         i++;
         logInfo("Mail ID: " + emailID);
         if(i > TIMEOUT_MAX_TIME_WAITING_FOR_MAIL_APPEARANCE) throw new RuntimeException("Email ID not found");
     }while(emailID == null);

     return emailID;
}
```

And the call:

```
String fake = waitFor(() -> getFakeMailID(getMessagesList(fieldName, url), MAIL_FROM, getCurrentDate(), subject));

String google = waitFor(() -> getEmailId(fieldName, subject, mailProvider));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getGoogleMailID` and `getFakeMailID` are two completely different methods and cannot be merged, the best solution would be

```
public static String waitForGoogleEmailID(String fieldName, String subject, String mailProvider) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String emailID = ""; int i = 0;
        do{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            emailID = getEmailId(fieldName, subject, mailProvider);
            i++;
            logInfo("Mail ID: " + emailID);
            if(i > TIMEOUT_MAX_TIME_WAITING_FOR_MAIL_APPEARANCE) 
      throw new RuntimeException("Email ID not found");
        } while(emailID == null);
        
    return emailID;
}
```

Then you would define a method that calls the different methods based on the provider parameter with a nice and clean switch case:

```
public String getEmailID(String fieldName, String subject, String provider) {
    switch (provider) {
         case “Google”:
              return getGoogleMailID(…);
         case “Fake”:
              return getFakeMailID(…);
         default:
              return “”;
    }
}
```

Since you’re calling both methods from different spots you clearly can pass the string parameter “provider”

PS: you didn’t ask but still you can use the for loop in your case

```
String emailID = null;
for(int i=0; emailID==null; i++) {
    …
}
```